# knockout mapping object array to observable array and create computed property foreach object

Tags: knockout.js

I want to map a json array data to observablearray in the following way:

```
var modell = function() {


    self.activities = ko.observableArray();
    ...


    ko.mapping.fromJS(dataJson, {}, self.activities);
    // as a result I can use self.activities[0].FirstName or other properties
}
```

Each activity is complex object. 
For simplicity, we can assume that there are two properties within each activity - `FirstName` and `LastName`. This works nice, but is it possible to write 
mapping options that will create computed observable `FullName` for each activity?

So, I need to reference like self.activities[0].FirstName, as well as self.activities[0].FullName, where FirstName is simple observable, but FullName is computed.

**EDIT:**
Here is JSFiddle of one try suggested below http://jsfiddle.net/5ScWn/ && http://jsfiddle.net/8PK6F/, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use mapping options that will create computed observable(s) for each item in an observable array. Try the following:

```
        var mappingOptions = {
            'activities': {
                create: function (options) {
                    return (new (function () {
                        this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
                            return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName;
                        }, this);

                        ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this); // continue the std mapping
                    })());
                }
            }
        };
```

and then use it via `ko.mapping.fromJS(dataJson, mappingOptions, self.activities);`

Comment: Am I missing something, but 'activities' never are reached? This could be because dataJson doesn't have 'activities' mapping element, but is array of obects?

Comment: Here is my fiddle with your example: http://jsfiddle.net/5ScWn/ or this http://jsfiddle.net/8PK6F/, in this example I have more complex user object, can it make problems?

Comment: @renathy I updated the first fiddle you posted [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ScWn/1/). I moved the computed `userFullName` up one level out of the `User` object though. If you wanted to keep it within the `User`, you'd have to add addtl mapping options to create a `User` observable for each item in the `Activities` observable array.