# ASP.NET MVC and knockout.js map from json and add nested computed variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I want to add computed field to knockout VM. In server side I have a model:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class PersonsOverviewModel {
    public Person[] Persons { get; set; }
}
```

In client side VM I want each Person to have computed field FullName, the VM should be generated from json data, this is how I did it:

```
var overviewVM = null; //default value
function Init(data){ // data is serialized model from server
   overviewVm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, overviewVm);
   $.each(overviewVm.Persons(), function (index, person) {
        person.FullName = ko.computed(function () { // add FullName field to each person
            return person.Name() + person.Surname();
        });
    });
 }
```

It works as expected when binding to the table. However after a data refresh from the server I'm getting exception at

```
 overviewVm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, overviewVm);
```

which says, that data cannot be mapped because FullName is missing. If I'm to set overviewVm to null before mapping from JS, it will map successfully, but for some reason wont update table, if I try to unbind and bind again it will add correct values to the table but wont remove the old ones.
This is how table looks like:

```
<table id="coverview-table" class="grid">
<thead class="gridHeader">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>FullName</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Persons">
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Surname"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: FullName"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I know that I can find another way to put a FullName into the table, but this is just simplified version of my situation and I want to find out the right way to work with knockout and data refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var mappingOptions = {
      'Persons': {
          create: function (options) {
              return (new(function () {
                  this.FullName = ko.computed(function () {
                      return this.Name() + this.Surname();
                  }, this);

                  ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this); // continue the standard mapping
              })());
          }
      }
  };
```

then use the `mappingOptions` whenever you map your data

`ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions, overviewVm);`

Possible duplicate of [knockout mapping object array to observable array and create computed property foreach object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464454/knockout-mapping-object-array-to-observable-array-and-create-computed-property-f/21465458#21465458)